# Volatile and sequence point

Tags: c, language-lawyer, volatile

Given the following code:

```
unsigned int global_flag = 0;

void exception_handle()
{
    global_flag = 1;
}

void func()
{
    /* access will cause exception which will assign global_flag = 1
       then execution continues */
    volatile unsigned int x = *(unsigned int *)(0x60000000U); /* memory protection unit configured to raise exception upon accessing this address */

    if (global_flag == 1)
    {
        /* some code */
    }
}
```

Given the fact that `volatile` [must not be reordered across sequence points](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Volatiles.html):

> The minimum requirement is that at a sequence point all previous
>   accesses to volatile objects have stabilized and no subsequent
>   accesses have occurred

And given the following about [sequence points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point):

> sequence points occur in the following places ... (1) .. (2) .. (3) **At the end of a full expression**. This category includes expression
>   statements (such as the assignment **a=b**;), return statements, the
>   controlling expressions of **if**, switch, while, or do-while statements,
>   and all three expressions in a for statement.

Is it promised that `volatile unsigned int x = *(unsigned int *)(0x60000000U);` will take place before `if (global_flag == 1)` (in the binary asm, the CPU out-of-order execution is not relevant here) ?

According to the citations above, `volatile unsigned int x = *(unsigned int *)(0x60000000U);` must be evaluated before the end of next sequence point, and `volatile unsigned int x = *(unsigned int *)(0x60000000U);` is a sequence point by itself, so is that means that every `volatile` assignment is evaluated at the assignment time?

If the answer to above question is no, than next sequence point is at the **end** of the `if`, does it mean that something like that can be executed:

```
if (global_flag == 1)
{
    volatile unsigned int x = *(unsigned int *)(0x60000000U);
    /* some code */
}
```

System is an embedded one- ARM cortex m0, single core, single thread application.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then "yes" to the first question? Why do you think it could be "no"? Of course if compiler can know your code must result in Undefined Behavior, it can assume for example that the code will never be reached and optimize it out entirely... *You can't rely on Undefined Behavior working in defined way in C!*

Comment: Is a lack of `volatile` on `global_flag` definition a mistake or intentional choice in your example?

Comment: @hyde Of course, many lowlevel-programming environments support code patterns, which are _in general_ undefined behaviour, in a defined and deterministic way.

Comment: AFAICS, this is not guaranteed as you have it currently, but if you define your global variable as `volatile`, it should be.

Comment: There's a fun and subtle point here: Your code doesn't contain assignment, just an initialization, and I believe there is no sequence point at the end of a definition with an initializer. I also believe this is a defect in the standard.

Comment: @Ctx Yeah sure, but that doesn't really go well together with [tag:C] and [tag:language-lawyer] tag combination. C standard guarantees nothing about Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: `global_flag`  is intentional not volatile (for learning purpose)

Comment: Where is the undefined behavior here? is it the asynchronous access to `global_flag` ?

Comment: `*(unsigned int *)(ILLEGAL_ADDRESS)` seems rather undefined behaviour to me.

Comment: according to which C rule?

Comment: What is `ILLEGAL_ADDRESS` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk question edited

Comment: @user2162550 I don't have C standard handy, nor time to dig it out, but from the top of my head, dereferencing pointer to illegal address is undefined behaviour. Even *having* a pointer with bad value (such as more than 1 step beyond end of on array) is undefined behaviour by the standard. Yes, C standard is kinda crazy that way. You might want to consider inline asm to access the address, if you want to play it safe with over-zealously optimising compilers etc.

Comment: @hyde freeing a malloced pointer leaves you with an invalid pointer in a pointer variable for example.

Comment: @Ctx I'm sure the standard covers that case as well... I would hazard a guess (some C language lawyer, feel free to pitch in), that while *having* a stale pointer to previously valid address is defined behaviour, dereferencing it certainly is undefined behaviour, and I would speculate that even previously valid `ptr++` probably is undefined after `free()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your snippet the variable `global_flag` is not volatile, so nothing prevents the compiler from moving the access to `global_flag` across sequence points or to remove it entirely if circumstances allow it. It does not make sense to talk about the order of the access to `x` and the access to `global_flag` because the latter is not an observable event, only the former is.

(Also note that there is no `volatile` qualifier in the expression `*(unsigned int *)(0x60000000U)`. I think it is really that expression that you wish to treat specially, but your code does not do that. The compiler is allowed to produce code that evaluates `*(unsigned int *)(0x60000000U)` well in advance, then does a ton of other stuff it has on its plate, then assigns the value that was obtained to `x` and this would satisfy the constraints that the C standards place on `volatile` lvalues.)

If your snippet had `unsigned int volatile global_flag = 0;` and `*(volatile unsigned int *)(0x60000000U)` then the answer to the question “Is it promised that …” would be an unambiguous “yes”.

Comment: But isnt' the volatile evaluation is based on abstract machine rules (no optimization) ? And also if `global_flag` was `volatile` and also I would volatile the initializer`*(volatile unsigned int *)(0x60000000U)` as well, does the sequence point that resides between `*(unsigned int *)(0x60000000U)` and `global_flag == 1` (with relation to @melpomene comment of the @Kamul Cuk answer) would promise the desired order ?

Comment: @user2162550 The evaluation of volatile lvalues is based on abstract machine rules. The evaluation of everything else is “as if”. For instance, there is no access to `a`, no access to `b` and no addition in the following function: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/NUVOA0 , despite `x` being a volatile variable.

Comment: @user2162550 yes, if you make `global_flag` and `*(unsigned int *)(0x60000000U)` volatile, then the sequence points that exists between any pairs of accesses to them will guarantee that they are accessed in the same order in the assembly code as in the source code.

Comment: I still think this is a myth created by compiler vendors. All expressions that access a volatile objects must be "evaluated as specified by the semantics". Semantics meaning pretty much "the whole C standard". Where the expression initializing the volatile variable `x` is clearly sequenced before `if (global_flag == 1)`. The compiler is not allowed to optimize this by re-ordering the operations and nothing in the C standard supports that notion! However, the definition of observable behavior speaks against it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it promised that volatile unsigned int x = *(unsigned int *)(ILLEGAL_ADDRESS); will take place before if (global_flag == 1)

From informative [C11 AnnexC](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#C) (added newlines/formatting for readability):

> The following are the sequence points described in 5.1.2.3:
>   ...
>   - Between the evaluation of a full expression and the next full expression to be evaluated.
>   -    The following are full expressions:
>   -    an initializer that is not part of a compound literal (6.7.9);
>   -    the expression in an expression statement (6.8.3);
>   -    the controlling expression of a selection statement (if or switch) (6.8.4);
>   -    the controlling expression of a while or do statement (6.8.5);
>   -    each of the (optional) expressions of a for statement (6.8.5.3);
>   -    the (optional) expression in a return statement (6.8.6.4).

As the `*(unsigned int *)(ILLEGAL_ADDRESS);` is an initializer (assignment expression)  and the initializer is not part of a compound literal, it is a full expression. The next full expression is the controlling statement in `if`, so between `if` and the initialization of `x` there is a sequence point.

And from the famous [C11 5.1.2.3p6](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3p6):

> The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
>
> Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.
>   ...

As `x` is a volatile object, it is initialized strictly to the abstract machine, so after the sequence point it has to have the rvalue equal to the result of `*(unsigned int *)(ILLEGAL_ADDRESS)` operation.

So yes, the initialization of `x` object must happen before the control expression inside the `if`.

On undefined behavior, there's the good quote from [C11 6.5.3.2p4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p4):

> If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary * operator is undefined.

As you commented:

> accessing address 0x60000000 is not permitted in my system memory model

one can deduce that `(unsigned int*)0x60000000` is an invalid pointer, so the unary * operator should [spawn dragons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: what is `abstract machine` ?

Comment: "*so between `if` and the initialization of `x` there is a sequence point*" - no, there isn't, at least not in the part of the standard you quoted.

Comment: @user2162550 [5.1.2.3.p1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3p1) Generally a machine with a compiler without an optimization. So each access is kind-of volatile and performed and generates code.

Comment: @melpomene Between evaluation of two full expression there is a sequence point. An initializer is a full expression. The controling expression in `if` is a full expression. Between initializer and controlling expression in `if` there is a sequence point. Is there a flaw in this logic?

Comment: @KamilCuk There is a sequence point at the end of `*(unsigned int *)(ILLEGAL_ADDRESS)` (the initializer) and there is a sequence point at the end of `global_flag == 1` (the condition). I don't see a sequence point after the initialization of `x`.

Comment: So this is what you meant in your comment! So the expression `*(unsigned int *)(ILLEGAL_ADDRESS)` must be evaluated before `global_flag == 1`, but the assignment/initialization on `x = ...;` may happen elsewhere? So the question is [C11 6.7.9.p8](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p8) _when_ is the initial value stored to the object? Maybe [C11 6.2.4p6](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p6)`If an initialization is specified for the object, it is performed each time the declaration or compound literal is reached in the execution of the block`

Comment: @melpomene very interesting. Does the standard says anything about where the initialization takes place with relation to the sequence point that resides between initializer expression and the `if` control statement ?

Comment: @melpomene: Yes, at a language-lawyer level, the C standard seems to have missed a point here. On the other hand, initialization is not a side effect (this is not an assigment), and “An initializer specifies the initial value stored in an object.” If `x` exists, it has been initialized. In practice, any compiler is going to treat the initialization as integral to evaluating the initializer.

Comment: While there is a sequence point for the initializer of `x`, there is nothing to  require the evaluation of `global_flag == 1` to be sequenced after that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "*If `x` exists, it has been initialized.*" This is not necessarily true. Initialization happens when execution reaches the definition of `x`, but `x`'s lifetime starts before that (on entry to the surrounding block). I.e. it's possible to access `x` before its definition.

Comment: @melpomene: Okay, the object exists before it is initialized, but, still, any compiler is going to treat the initialization as integral to evaluating the initializer. The C standard may have missed some wording here, but it is clear the sequence point after the initializer is intended to cover the initialization, not just the expression evaluation.

Comment: @melpomene If the sequence point was not intended to be after the initialization, then the snippet `int x = 1; x++;` would contain undefined behavior. This cannot have been the intention of the committee.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I know, but it does have undefined behavior.

Comment: @melpomene if you really think so, you should file a defect report instead of trying to convince people on SO.

Comment: Any `;` marks the end of the full expression and can therefore be regarded as a sequence point.

Comment: Also, initialization requires a declarator. C17 6.7.6/3: "A full declarator is a declarator that is not part of another declarator. **The end of a full declarator is a sequence point**."